# Text Box not saving in wordpress theme settings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme with theme options in wordpress. I like to add a dynamic add and remove textbox using jquery inside the theme settings page. My query is,

theme_settings.php

```
   <?php
function theme_settings_init(){
    register_setting( 'theme_settings', 'theme_settings' );
}

function add_settings_page() {
add_menu_page( __( 'Theme Settings' ), __( 'Theme Settings' ), 'manage_options', 'settings', 'theme_settings_page');
}

//add actions
add_action( 'admin_init', 'theme_settings_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_settings_page' );

//start settings page
function theme_settings_page() {

if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['updated'] ) )
$_REQUEST['updated'] = false;

?>

<div>

<div id="icon-options-general"></div>
<h2><?php _e( 'Theme Settings' ) //your admin panel title ?></h2>

<?php
//show saved options message
if ( false !== $_REQUEST['updated'] ) : ?>
<div><p><strong><?php _e( 'Options saved' ); ?></strong></p></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<form method="post" action="options.php">

<?php settings_fields( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
<?php $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' ); ?>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
        <?php
    $counter = 1;
    while (get_option('textbox'.$counter) && $counter <= 10) {
      echo '<div id="TextBoxDiv'.$counter.'">
        <input type="textbox" id="theme_settings[textbox'.$counter.'] name="theme_settings[textbox'.$counter.']" >
        </div>';
      $counter++;
    }
        ?>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
    <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>


<p><input name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes" type="submit"></p>
</form>


</div><!-- END wrap -->
<?php
}
```

and my javascript file is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    $('<div id="TextBoxDiv'+counter+'"></div>').append(
'<input type="text" name="theme_settings[textbox' + counter + 
']" id="theme_settings[textbox' + counter + ']" value="" >').appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     });
  });
```

Now my question is, In the theme settings page, the add action and remove action works very fine but while saving the theme setting options the added textbox dissappears. It happens while refreshing the page too. 
Please anyone help me how to keep those added textbox remains same if saving the theme options page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append()` instead of `.after().html()`. This way your code goes inside the corresponding div element. I made use of jQuery also.

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
'<input type="text" name="theme_settings[textbox' + counter + 
']" id="theme_settings[textbox' + counter + ']" value="" >');
```

should be

```
$('<div id="TextBoxDiv'+counter+'"></div>').append(
'<input type="text" name="theme_settings[textbox' + counter + 
']" id="theme_settings[textbox' + counter + ']" value="" >').appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup');
```

To make the text boxes appear you need a while loop like this:

```
$counter = 1;
while (get_option('textbox'.$counter) && $counter <= 10) {
  echo '<div id="TextBoxDiv'.$counter.'">
    <input type="textbox" id="theme_settings[textbox'.$counter.'] name="theme_settings[textbox'.$counter.']" >
    </div>';
  $counter++;
}
```

When you save them you could do this:

```
$counter = 0;
while (isset($_POST['theme_settings']['textbox'.$counter']) && $counter <= 10) {
  update_option('textbox'.$counter, $_POST['theme_settings']['textbox'.$counter']);
  $counter++;
}
// now remove the rest of them if they were previously set
// for example we now set only 5 of them and there were 10 before
// continue with counter from where we left in the previous while loop
while ($counter <= 10) {
  update_option('textbox'.$counter, false);
  $counter++;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function theme_settings_page() {
  $updated = false;

  if (isset($_REQUEST['updated'])) {
    update_option('theme_settings', $_POST['theme_settings']);
    $updated = true;
  }

  // ....

  if ($updated) {
    echo '<div><p><strong>';
      _e( 'Options saved' );
    echo '</strong></p></div>';
  }

  $counter = 1;
  $options = get_option('theme_settings');
  while (isset($options['textbox'.$counter])) {
    echo '<div id="TextBoxDiv'.$counter.'">
        <input type="textbox" id="theme_settings[textbox'.$counter.'] name="theme_settings[textbox'.$counter.']" value="'.$options['textbox'.$counter].'" />
        </div>';
    $counter++;
  }

  echo '<input type="hidden" name="updated" value="1" />';

  // the rest of your form
}
```

Comment: Could you post your saving script here?

Comment: i will edit my question with your answer.. just see it

Comment: I see you updated your question, but I still do not see where you do the actual save. You added just the while loop that displays the fields on the page. In order to help you I need to see how you save your data.

Comment: You're not saving them. You can do that by adding   `if (isset($_REQUEST['updated'])) { update_option('theme_settings', $_POST['theme_settings']); $_REQUEST['updated'] = true;}`  at the beginning of your `theme_settings_page()` function.  In `while` change `get_option('textbox'.$counter)` to `isset($options['textbox'.$counter'])`.  Also, you have to add a hidden input to your form named updated.